# Create a dev/test cloud on a box or two

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, openstack

So I have a similar question to [Recommended setup for a "hom dev cloud"? I want to run VM's on an old desktop basically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358943/recommended-setup-for-a-hom-dev-cloud-i-want-to-run-vms-on-an-old-desktop-ba). Everything I've seen for installing EC2 eucalyptus or openstack has been on bare metal. I tried to install on ISO on a vm, but it wouldn't install to a VM. Is it possible to have test environment on one server where I can programmatically spin up vms as I would with a public cloud?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested in deploying your cloud as a VM, you should also consider [Apache Cloudstack](http://cloudstack.apache.org/). Have a look at [DevCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/DevCloud) for a VM image.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this will work for openstack http://devstack.org/guides/single-vm.html. Is there anything similar for ec2 eucalyptus?

Answer (score 0):

For eucalyptus you could take a look at eucadev:

http://sigtt.in/articles/2013/11/25/introducing-eucadev/